# "Export>GreasePencil as SVG" line thickness differs from Viewport

Tags: export, grease-pencil, svg

When exporting my GreasePencil object as an SVG I am getting a different thickness on my lines to what I see on the Viewport.

As a minimal reproduction:

1. I created a new .blend file, I used the 2D Animation defaults.
2. I created a circle and a line using default settings.
3. I go into object mode, select the GreasePencil object and click *File > Export > Export GreasePencil as SVG*

This is what it should look like, this is what I see from the Viewport as well as the result of rendering it as a png:
[image: png-test]

As you can see I purposefully left a small gap between the line and circle.

If I export the GreasePencil as an SVG I get the following:
[image]

They are now overlapping and appear a lot thicker.

How do I solve this issue and ideally, how do I avoid reproducing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this *Export Grease Pencil to SVG * feature in a very limited way, so I'm sure that this is not the most sophisticated solution, but maybe it can help.

If you select a stroke and click on *Stroke > Outline*, Blender converts the stroke to perimeter and it will appear in the SVG export with the correct size.